# Adding user input to a Select-String command

Tags: powershell, while-loop, select-string

I'm currently trying to create a select-string command to determine if users in my company are still showing up in certain directories. My current command is a follows:

```
Select-String -path "C:\filepath\*.csv" -Pattern "<string>" |
    Format-Table -Property LineNumber,Line,Path -Wrap |
    Out-File "C:\outfile.txt"
```

The current command means I'd need to alter the content of the Pattern parameter each time before running the script. What I'd like to do instead is to request my input for the string when I run the script. Is there a while loop I can add to this command to request user input?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the head of your script:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $True)]
    [System.String]
    $Pattern
)

Select-String -Path C:\filepath\*.csv -Pattern $Pattern |
    Tee-Object -FilePath C:\outfile.txt |
    Format-Table -Property LineNumber, Line, Path -Wrap
```

When you call the script, the attribute makes sure you give an argument to `-Pattern`.  You can add further attributes if you want this to not be null (`[ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]`), etc.

As an aside, never pipe from formatters.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why shouldn't I pipe after the Format-Table?

Comment: @m_lloyd Because formatters are only intended to be used to display to the console.  They consist of `Format.Format*` data types that you can't actually do anything with.  `Get-Process | Format-Table` and now you can't access the process details anymore.